# UITableView Nested in UICollectionViewCell with No Margins

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my current project I am using a UITableView nested inside each UICollectionViewCell. Within the UITableView I have a number of custom UITableViewCells separated by borders as seen in the screenshot.

I am wanting each border tp stretch the entire length of the screen from left to right, but as you can see in the first image each border stops short of the outer edge of the screen.

In the second screenshot I have put a border around the entire edge of the UITableView to confirm that it is indeed the sizing of the UITableView that is causing this issue.

In the Storyboard the top, bottom, left and right constraints of the UITableView are set to be the same as UICollectionViewCell.

In the UICollectionViewCell's properties I have set fixed margins all to be 0, and "Safe Area Relative Margins" has been deselected.

Also when initializing the UICollectionViewCell I have tried:

```
self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Meq.png)

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc6eI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot... Forgot that contentViews were a thing.

Used: `self.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)` and everything was peachy.